# Scala Byte type can contain -128 but not 128

Tags: scala, byte, primitive-types

I'm new to Scala. I've encountered a strange fact that it's `Byte` type can contain -128 but not 128.

```
scala> val overflow1NegByte = -129:Byte
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(-129)
 required: Byte
       val overflow1NegByte = -129:Byte
                               ^

scala> val overflow1NegByte = -128:Byte
overflow1NegByte: Byte = -128

scala> val overflow1PosByte = 128:Byte
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(128)
 required: Byte
       val overflow1PosByte = 128:Byte
                              ^

scala> val overflow1PosByte = 127:Byte
overflow1PosByte: Byte = 127
```

Apparently it feels that, to indicate a negative number, first flag is used. For positive numbers also this flag is reserved. This is understandable. But, why one more negative number than the positives.

Comment: A very simple answer: with both -128 and 128 you have 2 * 128 + 1 = 257 numbers (including 0) you want to squeeze into on byte, which has only 8 bits, i.e. 256 combinations. So you have to sacrifice either 128 or -128. Why 128? It's a bit longer story.

Comment: Go to the REPL and invoke `MinValue` and `MaxValue` on each of the integral types, `Byte`, `Short`, `Int`, and `Long`. (In other words, `Byte.MinValue`, `Byte.MaxValue`, `Short.MinValue`, etc.)  You'll see that this pattern is consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's [the range of a `Byte` on the JVM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

> `byte`: The byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer.
>   It has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive).

As explained, this is because of [Two's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Let's explain a bit more. A byte holds 8 bits, and if we wanted to represent the number -128. We start from 128:

```
10000000
```

And we invert the bits:

```
01111111
```

And add 1. We get back:

```
10000000
```

This is how -128 is represented. This means that the biggest signed number we can represent with Twos Complement is:

```
01111111
```

Which is equivalent to 127. This aligns with the fact that Twos Complement uses the MSB (Most Significant Bit) to represent the sign.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement):

> An N-bit two's-complement numeral system can represent every integer
>   in the range −(2N − 1) to +(2N − 1 − 1)

So, we have:

```
-(2^7-1) = (-128) to +(2^7-1 - 1) = +(127)
```

Comment: Ok. But, why one more negative than the positive numbers. It should contain same number of positive and negative numbers.

Comment: I would be worth mentioning that in two's complimented system the most significant bit represents negative numbers, so max. positive number can only have 7 bits, hence 127. It's technically not because of the way of flipping bits, you could choose 10000000 as 128 and 10000001 as -127 and additions would work fine, divisions would be a mess though.